# How to choose threshold value in MCD-based Mahalanobis distances?

Tags: time-series, python, covariance, outliers, mahalanobis

A dataset is having 2 or more timeseries
eg: with two timeseries x and y
[image: Timeseries]

I need to predict the slope and intercept using Linear regression model b/w x & y.
But my data can have **Outliers**

My Approach:

1. Calculate Mahalanobis distance using MCD
2. Find the Outlier using some threshold value, if greater than threshold then outlier
3. For finding threshold, I chose quantile and chi-square but for all datasets it is not calculating outlier, By playing with it I am able to find but I want to automate this
4. After finding Outliers, Remove the outliers from the dataset
5. Then Build the model using Linear regression

My problem is **how to choose the threshold value for removing the outlier** that will work in all cases or atleast calculation of slope and intercept cases? I cannot check the plot of the data of everytime, because I am writing an python script which will build best model between the timeseries and give slope and intercept as output.

I also explored the robust regression, but I want to keep this simple